# How exactly date/time works in MySQL with timezones?

Tags: mysql, time, timezone, date

My understanding was:

- everything is UTC internally
- dates are displayed in @@session.time_zone timezone for current session
- if I do `INSERT` with `+02:00` TZ set and insert `2015-05-15 10:54` it is parsed and stored as `2015-05-15 08:54` UTC.
- when I change to `UTC` TZ it should now display `2015-05-15 08:54`
- what happens instead is that it still displays `2015-05-15 10:54`

What am I doing wrong? Or is this expected? I read quite some articles about datetime in MySQL but I am still not sure.

Comment: What exactly do you change to `UTC`  at step 4?

Comment: The DB has Etc/UTC (time zone is set to SYSTEM and system has Etc/UTC) by default so I connect again (without setting `@@session.time_zone`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That only applies to `TIMESTAMP` fields. `DATETIME` fields are left as-is.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html